# GTA5 Online: If I log off and come back in an hour will the garage buy cars again?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Okay, so I want to sell another car to the garage but it takes a full game day.  Do I need to be logged in with my game on to do this, or can I turn it off, come back in 48 minutes, and sell again?

Also, do I have to wait 48 minutes, or will it be at midnight of the following GTA-day that they will start purchasing again?

THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

It's 48 minutes in "real life minutes" or 24 hours in game starting at the minute you have sold your car.

So yeah you could close your game, go outside your house, kill some peoples, go into a strip club and come back online 48 minutes later to sell another car.

Comment: I think we're having a little confusion with reality here, man.  Those are things you do IN the game.  Calmly just take a couple steps back here...